# lsWires lightswitch html cluent

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I am trying to implement the lsWires tool in my lightswitch html application however it gives me an error saying lsWire is not defined. I have ran the sample projects online and they all have the same error.

Is lsWire actually a work in progress or is there something I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a reference to the script and stylesheet in your default.htm file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/lsWires.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/lsWires.js"></script>
```

There are actually a bunch of requirements.  I suggest you take a look at this guide: http://blog.ofanitguy.com/2014/05/07/lightswitch-2013-html-client-easily-add-multi-item-selection-to-your-lists-and-tables/

Comment: lsWire.enableListToBeMultiSelect(contentItem);

Comment: im trying to get the selected items from the list and put it in the database but its only taking the first selected item. any idea? do i need to get the selected items and store it in a variable?

Comment: Try this:     screen.SelectedObjects = [];
var list = screen.findContentItem("NameOfYourContentItem");
    var count = lsWire.list.selectedCount(list);
    var selected = lsWire.list.selected(list);

    screen.SelectedObjects = selected;

Comment: my intellisense doesnt pick up that version of lswires but ill give it a go

Comment: Hi Kris I have code that adds the records to the DB. If i pick 8 records for example 2 from each category(I have 4 drop down lists) itll only take the first selected. So if i choose CLASS A and CLASS B itll insert 2 records but itll both record as CLASS A and such so for every dropdown in my collection.

Comment: myapp.AuditAssets.Submit_execute = function (screen) {

    var list = screen.findContentItem("Conditions");
    var count = lsWire.countOfSelectedListItems(list);
    var selected = lsWire.getSelectedListItems(list);
 
    
    _.forEach(selected, function (item) {
        var assetcondition = myapp.activeDataWorkspace.JMSData.AssetConditions.addNew();
        assetcondition.Asset = screen.ScannedAssetsByProject.selectedItem;
       
        assetcondition.Condition = screen.Conditions.selectedItem;
        
    });
 
}  I think it may be the last line of code I am fairly new to js

Comment: Your forEach will set the 'item' parameter as it loops.  Some ForEach methods will have a different signature, e.g foreach(items, function(index, item) { do stuff with 'item' });

Comment: so shud i use something other than the forEach?

Comment: My point is: Use the forEach.  Grab your data from the function(item) parameter.  I.e. use the 'item' variable to retrieve your selected value each loop.

Comment: still pretty confusing any code snippet that could get me going?